# Oracle: Restricting "Other Users" visible

Tags: oracle, security, permissions

I'm a novice in administration and trying to improve security on our Oracle database.

Currently, a non-privileged user can see a list of all other users in SQL Developer by expanding the "Other Users" icon, in the database navigation tree.

How does one restrict privileges so users will only see those (other) users that have granted them a privilege on some object (rather than all users, whether privilege has been granted or not).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't (at least not reasonably).  Tools like SQL Developer are going to query `ALL_USERS` to get the list of users and that will show all the users in the database to any user that has the ability to log in.  Is it really a security risk for A to know that a user B exists if A can't see anything else about B?

While I would strongly advise against it, you may be able to work around the problem by creating an `ALL_USERS` view in the nonprivileged user's schema (or creating a private synonym to a view in a different schema) that has the same structure as `ALL_USERS` but has less data.  Since most tools don't qualify the names of data dictionary tables `SYS.ALL_USERS` rather than just `ALL_USERS`, this trick generally works.  There are substantial risks, though.  Inevitably, there are unexpected downsides when some install script expects that the data dictionary is "normal", eventually someone will use a tool that does fully qualify the data dictionary table name, etc.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Our goal was "in case one user is compromised, at least it does not give away the usernames of all others, which may allow someone to try and work their way forwards".

Comment: Yes, it's a security risk to disclose usernames.  There are worse risks, and you have to consider the user population and sensitivity of the data in the system.  It might be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Probably SQL Developer query the table (or view I don't remember) `all_users`. So you will need to revoke this grant (as sysdba):

```
revoke select on ALL_USERS from PUBLIC;
```

And also grant this to users that you want to allow the select.

EDIT:

I agree with @Justin Cave's answer. This have risks and also, he brings a good question:

> Is it really a security risk for A to know that a user B exists if A
>   can't see anything else about B?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question:
Is it really a security risk for A to know that a user B exists if A can't see anything else about B?

I thinks yes, if user A (unprivileged) knows the existance of B, it might try to connect (brute force) and:
option a: A succeeds, and B is a privileged user
option b: A fails because B has a strong password and there are some profile restristions on user B that after several intents from A to connect as B, user B gets locked and it might be a problem of Denial of service.

Answer (score 0):

A user with no system privileges, with roles "AUTHENTICATEDUSER" and "CONNECT" will be able to log in normally and access own objects, but will not be able to select other users, or expand "Other Users" in SQL Developer.